# Java EE Template Engine Recommendations?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jstl, template-engine, torque

Looking to expand a current Java EE project using JSTL and Apache Torque with some sort of template engine so we can easily modify the views.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I think [Freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/) is the leading Java template engine. The other one is [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) but it is not as popular as it used to be.